Load Local Image using phaser js
I'm downloading some code from Rosebud AI, and when I start with their link or an external link, it works. However, when I try to use my own local storage to play the assets, it's not working.
    this.load.audio("buttonSound", "assets/Button.mp3");
    this.load.audio("backgroundMusic", "assets/bg.mp3");
    this.load.audio("stoneDropSound", "assets/StoneDrop.mp3");

My Folder Structure
Folder Structure
How To Load it Just it is

Well if you are using a local webserver it should work, But if you browsing the html file locally (without a webserver) this could be the cause of your issue.

Checkout the official getting started for detail about webserver vs local file.

If you are using a webserver, and are have this issue. Are there some error messages in the browser console? If so these error message might help find the exact problem.

It doesn't matter because I'm using Phaser.js. Is there an exact way to call the assets?

I don't understand what you mean, my answer is refering to phaser.js . And yes this is the way how on load assets, depending on the assets. Your "code" just shows audio files. There are many factor that can cause issues. But honestly your code snippet doesn't reveal much information. And if there is no error in the browser console, it is hard to say what the issue is.
